# Find average occurrences in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I got a query that displays the following

```
SELECT 
hospital,
initials
FROM patients p, visits v
WHERE p.id=v.user_id
```

It returns a table like that:

```
Hospital 1 / ID123
Hospital 1 / ID123
Hospital 1 / ID123
Hospital 2 / ID134
Hospital 2 / ID134
Hospital 3 / ID567
Hospital 1 / ID789
```

As you see, Hospital 1 has one appearance with 3 similar IDs and one appearance with one ID.

I need a table that displays how often on average distinct IDs appear.

```
Hospital 1 / Average 2
Hospital 2 / Average 2
Hospital 3 / Average 1
```

That really wrecks my mind.

Comment: if https://stackoverflow.com/a/52171290/2469308 works for you, you may accept it as answer, by clicking on green tick :)

Comment: Use a proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 20 years.

Answer (score 3):

Move from Implicit joins to Explicit [JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp). We use [GROUP BY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) clause with [COUNT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp) function, to determine aggregate parameters like average. Try the following:

```
SELECT 
     hospital,
     COUNT(*)/COUNT(DISTINCT initials) AS average 
FROM patients p
INNER JOIN visits v ON v.user_id = p.id 
GROUP BY hospital
```

Answer (score 0):

Use group by and aggregation:

```
SELECT 
hospital,
count(*)/count(distinct initials)
FROM patients p inner join visits v
on p.id=v.user_id group by hospital
```

Comment: Thanks - that is the solution!

Answer (score 0):

looking to your sample  you could count  the distinct initials grouped by hospital

```
 SELECT hospital,
      count(distinct initials)
FROM patients p
inner join visits v on  p.id=v.user_id
group by hospital
order  by hospital
```

and you should avoid the old implict joi based  on where clause you should use explict inner join sintax